# Turning long fixed number to array Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, fixnum

Is there a method in ruby to turn fixnum like `74239` into an array like `[7,4,2,3,9]`?

Comment: The answer of mbds, using the `digits` method introduced in Ruby 2.4 makes all others obsolete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to take a round trip through string-land for this sort of thing:

```
def digits(n)
  Math.log10(n).floor.downto(0).map { |i| (n / 10**i) % 10 }
end

ary = digits(74239)
# [7, 4, 2, 3, 9]
```

This does assume that `n` is positive of course, slipping an `n = n.abs` into the mix can take care of that if needed. If you need to cover non-positive values, then:

```
def digits(n)
  return [0] if(n == 0)
  if(n < 0)
    neg = true
    n   = n.abs
  end
  a = Math.log10(n).floor.downto(0).map { |i| (n / 10**i) % 10 }
  a[0] *= -1 if(neg)
  a
end
```

Comment: @RyanBigg: Only if you've forgotten your high school math.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe not the most elegant solution:

```
74239.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)
```

Output:

```
[7, 4, 2, 3, 9]
```

Comment: `.map(&:to_i)` to get it a bit more elegant?

Comment: What happens to `-23.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)`?

Comment: I'm nitpicking a bit here, but `74239.to_s.chars` seems more appropriate than `74239.to_s.split('')`, especially when used in conjunction with `.map(&:to_i)` :)

Comment: I think `each_char` would be even more appropriate, as it would avoid the intermediate `Array` created by `chars`.

Comment: @Drenmi, I suppose `.chars` in Enumerator currently, not Array.

Answer (score 8):

As of Ruby 2.4, integers ([`FixNum` is gone in 2.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372649/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-fixnum/21411269#21411269)) have a built-in `digits` method that extracts them into an array of their digits:

```rb
74239.digits
=> [9, 3, 2, 4, 7]
```

If you want to maintain the order of the digits, just chain `reverse`:

```rb
74239.digits.reverse
=> [7, 4, 2, 3, 9]
```

Docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits

Answer (score 5):

The divmod method can be used to extract the digits one at a time

```
def digits n
  n= n.abs
  [].tap do |result|
    while n > 0 
      n,digit = n.divmod 10
      result.unshift digit
    end
  end
end
```

A quick benchmark showed this to be faster than using log to find the number of digits ahead of time, which was itself faster than string based methods.

```
bmbm(5) do |x|
  x.report('string') {10000.times {digits_s(rand(1000000000))}}
  x.report('divmod') {10000.times {digits_divmod(rand(1000000000))}}
  x.report('log') {10000.times {digits(rand(1000000000))}}
end

#=>
             user     system      total        real
string   0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.126119)
divmod   0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.023148)
log      0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.045285)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert to string and use the chars method:

```
74239.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)
```

Output:

```
[7, 4, 2, 3, 9]
```

Its a bit more elegant than splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Array.new` instead of `map`:

```
n = 74239

s = Math.log10(n).to_i + 1 # Gets the size of n

Array.new(s) { d = n % 10; n = n / 10; d }.reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 2.4, integers will have a [digits method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_preview2/Integer.html#method-i-digits).