# Separating integer values into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, fixnum

Is there an equivalent of the String chars method for fixnum? Am trying to separate an integer value by value into an array e.g. 1234 -> [1, 2, 3, 4] to then perform operations on the individual values.

Or is it better to convert into a string first, perform an operation (example x 2) and then join as integers? Like below:

```
    def method_name num
      num.to_s.chars.map{|x| x.to_i*2}.join.to_i
    end
```

Comment: Ok, apparently can be done without conversion to string: `Math.log10(1234).floor.downto(0).map { |i| (1234 / 10**i) % 10 }`
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: yeah, I meant something like that :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'd never even think of using something like this.. Do you think it makes any sense in terms of efficiency (or in any terms :))?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: efficiency is to be measured, but sometimes stringification is not available (in other languages, I mean), whereas this math-based approach always works. So it is useful to be aware of this one weird trick :)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that splits a number into individual digits, since that's generally a nonsense thing to do with a number. You could also do it the math-y way, but I don't see a distinct advantage to doing so given the requirements (so far).

I might prefer to split the conversion and multiplication, e.g.,

```
n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).map { |n| n * 2 }.join.to_i
```

It's a bit more versatile, and if, say, your multiplier changes, it's easy to change (not shown here, but there are ways).

Comment: `There's nothing that splits a number into individual digits` - [apparently there is :)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12908181/1772830)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Yep,  you can definitely do it via math, but I'd be a little surprised if it's more efficient or easier to understand. My point was that there's nothing *built in* that does this.

Comment: @DaveNewton just wait 10 days: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_rc1/Integer.html#method-i-digits

Comment: @steenslag That's pretty cool. Are there any other notable new methods as well?

Comment: @steenslag Curses!